# RabbitMq Consumer on AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, aws-lambda

From what I know, Lambdas are for listening to events and running a piece of code on response to those events.

The events need to be AWS services or HTTP endpoints.
If I have a **RabbitMq** service running on an **EC2 server** (Not using SQS), is it possible to have a **consumer** deployed on Lambda?

If possible, would this be the right thing to do?

Also, since lambdas are billed on compute time, I shouldn't be billed for when the queue is idle, right?

Comment: I don't know of any way for RabbitMQ to trigger an AWS Lambda invocation. You would have to schedule your Lambda function to run every minute or so and check the queue for messages. Also the last sentence in your question makes no sense.

Comment: It might not be general thing but i guess combination of SNS & Lambda you can use http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns-example.html

Comment: @MarkB Sorry. Update the last question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can probably install this on the same server as the rabbitMQ, and make it trigger the lambdas. I haven't tried myself though
https://github.com/AirHelp/rabbit-amazon-forwarder

As far as I understand, lambdas are billed by the running time, and you pay based on amount of memory (per gigabyte/second). So making a lambda wait all the time will probably be pretty expensive and hard to manage since it will time out. If you already have a server with RabbitMQ, use that for consuming the queue and calling the lambdas.

Answer (score 2):

You can now configure Amazon MQ for RabbitMQ as an event source for AWS Lambda.
Check the AWS blog.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-mq-for-rabbitmq-as-an-event-source-for-lambda/

Comment: how would you handle the possibility of dynamically generated queues as the event source for the lambda? In my setup queues are generated dynamically when a new user joins, so I wouldn't be able to specify the queue name ahead of time. Do you have any idea how to handle that? Thanks!